# failover support in spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration process that is used to integrate two systems in near real time expectation.
I need to build a fail-over process for this that may run on same or another machine.
Is there a inbuilt support for this in spring-integration?
If not, some ideas to implement this would be greatly helpful. 
I am thinking some sort of heartbeat messages on a message channel and if they don't arrive within a stipulated time-frame, activate the workflow, but i don't know how these can be achieved in spring-integration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details - types of communication etc but, generally, yes, it can be configured for failover - the default `DirectChannel` uses round-robin distribution between consumers by default, but you can configure it with a dispatcher that has `load-balancer="NONE"`. Then it will always try the first consumer and failover to the second on failure. You can also configure a circuit breaker advice on the first consumer so we fail fast (for some period of time) and only retry the first consumer once in a while.

As I said, if you can provide more details of your actual requirements, we can help with more specific answers.

Comment: I have a SI process (process 1)  that polls a database and processes the rows all the way to sending them over a SOAP call to another system. Which works great.

I want to deploy this to another machine (process 2) which should work as a backup process. For whatever reason if process 1 stops processing, the process 2 starts doing the job but otherwise it should stay dormant.

Comment: That's a little more complicated (we can easily failover to a backup SOAP system using the technique described above). You can use [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) to deploy your application; it will automatically take care of bringing up a new instance if it fails. We have an old solution presented at [Spring One a few years ago - video here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Implementing-HA-Architectures-Spring-Integration) - [code and slides here](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-ha-demo), but that's a bit out of date now and XD is the way to go.